# What platforms support rendering the Unicode combining character ⃠ around existing emoji?

Tags: unicode, emoji, platform, combining-marks

I'm trying to determine what platforms support adding the Unicode character  COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE BACKSLASH (  ⃠) around pre-existing emoji.  The only documentation I can find about using this composing character with emoji is from [Unicode Tech Report #51](http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/):

> Combining marks may be applied to emoji, just like they can be applied
>   to other characters. When that is done, the combination should take on
>   an emoji presentation. For example, a 1⃣ is represented as the
>   sequence "1" plus an emoji variation selector plus U+20E3 COMBINING
>   ENCLOSING KEYCAP. Systems are unlikely, however, to support arbitrary
>   combining marks with arbitrary emoji. Aside from U+20E3, the most
>   likely to be supported is:
>
> - U+20E0 COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE BACKSLASH, as an overlaid   ⃠, to
>     indicate a prohibition or “NO”
>
> For example:
>
> - ⃠  no microphones
> - ⃠  no flashes
> - ⃠  no guns No combining marks other than U+20E0 and U+20E3, however, are recommended for usage.

Note: Your platform/browser combination, like mine, might render each of those as examples as two distinct characters.  What platforms support them as rendering as one character?

Comment: Your examples render as separate characters for me on macOS because they include ordinary space characters (U+0020). The space cannot be selected or deleted. If I enter the example manually it's rendered as a pair of empty boxes: ⃠.